# Swift linux unit test @testable import fails

Tags: swift

I try to add Unit tests to my Swift project on Linux Ubuntu 16.04. Now I have the directory structure:

```
MyProject
|-Sources
| └MyProject
|  |-IPcalc.swift
|  └ main.swift
|
|-Tests
| |-MyProjectTests
| | └IPcalcTests.swift
| └ LinuxMain.swift
|
└ Package.swift
```

IPcalcTests.swift file:

```
import XCTest
@testable import IPcalc
...
```

LinuxMain.swift file:

```
import XCTest
@testable import IPcalcTests

XCTMain([
    testCase(IPcalcTests.allTests),
])
```

Package.swift file:

```
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "MyProject",
    products: [],
    dependencies: [],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "MyProject",
            dependencies: []),
        .testTarget(
            name: "MyProjectTests",
            dependencies: ["MyProject"]),
    ]
)
```

When I try to execute swift test , I get:

```
$ swift test
Compile Swift Module 'MyProjectTests' (2 sources)
/home/user/MyProject/Tests/MyProjectTests/IPcalcTests.swift:2:18: error: no such module 'IPcalc'
@testable import IPcalc
```

Why I could not import IPcalc class to IPcalcTests.swift?

Comment: I had something similar not long ago. The problem was that I needed to build the missing module first, manually, before the rest of the project. Does that help at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue happens because my app is executable, it has main.swift file. Unit Test don't work in this case, or I don't know how to use it. It is necessary to split project into projectApp target and projectLib target. projectApp will contain only main.swift and projectLib will contain the rest.

After that Unit Test works without any problems with projectLib target. More details about is here: https://riis.com/blog/swift-unit-testing-ubuntu/

https://www.raywenderlich.com/1072244-server-side-swift-testing-on-linux

Comment: Link above is broken now - the excellent article is available here:

https://theswiftpost.co/unit-tests-in-server-side-swift-api/